# How to get verbose output on Ubuntu Server while booting?

Tags: server, boot

There is no output form the init scripts on Ubuntu Server.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/542666

Is there any workaround? Such as installing plymouth or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub2
```

This will show kernel debug messages.