# Seeing Ubuntu Boot Process

Tags: 16.04

Rather than seeing this screen

[image: Splash screen]

I hope to see Ubuntu 16.04 booting process. How should I see that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get verbose output on Ubuntu Server while booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161190/how-to-get-verbose-output-on-ubuntu-server-while-booting)

Comment: Does this https://askubuntu.com/questions/98566/how-do-deactivate-plymouth-boot-screen  answer your question?

Comment: Just hit the `ESC` key when you see that screen.